# Trying to understand the concepts in ODEs text

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking through a textbook on ODEs and the first chapter is basically just definition after definition after definition without very many exercises or examples for me to get my head around the concepts.  So can someone recommend a book or paper that goes over some of the following concepts a little slower

- phase space,
- phase flow,
- integral curves,
- one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms, and
- motions

I'm looking for a resource to understand these concepts a little better, so a book that gives plenty of examples and exercises (bonus points if the book has solutions in the back) would be ideal.  Suggestions?

Comment: I suggest the two well known references: 1) The work by Hirsch and Smale: http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-Dynamical-Systems-Introduction/dp/0123820103      2)  The work by L. Perko: http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Equations-Dynamical-Systems-Mathematics/dp/0387951164

Comment: Which book are you reading?